# react.js arrow function returning noting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class Greeting extends React.Component {
    state={
        username:'u1',
        user:['u1','u2']
    }

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.uList=this.uList.bind(this);
    }

    uList = () =>{
        return this.state.user.map((u)=>{ 
            console.log(u);
            return <li>{u}</li>; 
        }); 
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            {this.uList}
                </div>

            );
    }
}
```

Complete code : https://pastebin.com/raw/Azi65Vnu

I'm trying react.js with cdn for the first time, it gives me just hello world, but not rendering the list.

**Why is that?**

Comment: Try calling the function `{this.uList()}`

Comment: Typo. You need to **call** the function, not just mention it. Add `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call function

```
render() {
  return (<div>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      {this.uList()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you really think that the question needs an answer or this will help any further readers? Please try to avoid answering to the typo questions...

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the function:

```
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      {this.uList()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you really think that the question needs an answer or this will help any further readers? Please try to avoid answering to the typo questions...

Comment: True, agreed! He would've genuinely tried his best before posting here on public forum may be! :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't call your method at all. You missed parenthesis `()`

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      {this.uList()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you really think that the question needs an answer or this will help any further readers? Please try to avoid answering to the typo questions...

Comment: I'd like to have an answer from OP point of view.